# How to header rowspan and colspan?

Tags: jquery, html, slickgrid, html-table

I think that SlickGrid is best jquery grid.

I need header rowspan/colspan feature.

But i cant find example.

Is not yet span feature in SlickGrid ?

And, I find the SlickGrid API or Document.

sorry i cant english not well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Colspan & rowspan of header for slickgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213644/colspan-rowspan-of-header-for-slickgrid)

Answer (score 0):

Colspan support has just been added, though it is a bit rough at the moment.
There is no rowspan support planned.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official example showing colspan on Github (new home for the project since Google Code)

http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-colspan.html