# Colspan & rowspan of header for slickgrid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I am just wondering if there is a way to provide colspan/rowspan to header and have multiple header rows.

Comment: Could you make it ? I am facing the same problematic.

Comment: I wasn't able to make it. I ended up doing something else that I don't remember.

Comment: I ended up creating my own datagrid ...

Comment: That is nice if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a secondary header row that the grid provides. You can use that to do whatever you need to.Check [here](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Grid-Options) for more information

Comment: Can you have a colspan in additional header? I know there is additional header option but I wasn't able to figure out adding colspan there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of colspan:
http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-colspan.html

As for rowspan, it's quite a bit more complicated, as you can see in the following Github issue:
https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/issues/381

***note that the active repository has changed from mleibman's to this one:
https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid